# How to uninstall Nvidia driver from centos7?

Tags: centos, boot, nvidia

Today I installed the NVIDIA driver on my laptop `dell inspiron 5558`.
I did that using the instructions [here in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9Yf71qh0i4)

But after rebooting I'm getting this

[image]

and I couldn't enter to the Operating system UI at all 
so I think that I should delete this driver.

How could I do that? 
or do you have another solution to my case?

Comment: Are you able to do a CTRL+ALT F2? switch from a graphical interface to a command line interface?

Comment: thank you for reply ....let us suppose that I could so...then what I should do after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the best solution for this problem

1-in this screen press `ctrl+Alt+F2` to open the terminal

2-write your user name and password

3-type `sudo yum autoremove nvidia*` then press `Enter` then type `y` to accept the remove

4-the previous command will delete that bad driver so that you could install a better driver in the future `but don't do that :)`

Answer (score 1):

#### If you need to modify grub at boot:

One option is to edit grub before selecting an image and changing your boot option to default to terminal session instead of a graphical load. the steps can be found here [How do I boot into single-user mode from GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/a/132983/324021). I know the answer for Ubuntu but it also works on CentOS, I have had to do this before.

#### If you are stuck at a graphical loading page:

If your system gets stuck trying to load a graphical interface, try and just do a `CTRL+ALT F2` (RHEL based systems) and get into a terminal session.

#### Once your in a terminal session:

Once you are signed into the terminal session, you can just `yum history` to pull up your install history and reverse your installs.

RedHat gives out a really good explanation on how to use `yum history` to rollback installs
[How to use yum history to roll back an update in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 , 7](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/64069)

Here is a Note for the yum history rollback from the given link.

> **Note:** Rollback of selinux, selinux-policy-*, kernel, glibc (dependencies of glibc such as gcc) packages to older version is not supported. Thus, downgrading a system to minor version (ex: RHEL6.1 to RHEL6.0) is not recommended as this might leave the system in undesired state. Use the yum history option for small update rollbacks.